# Scrollable child when max-height of parent is reached

Tags: html, css

My problem is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903840/scrollable-child-element-when-parent-reaches-its-max-height) but the difference I can see is that my parent div (`#container`) have a `min-height` and a `max-height` (no `height` as it should grow with its content), but the scrollable div (`#dynamic-part`) does not know its `height` nor `max-height` either. It should be scrollable when its parent has reached its `max-height`.

Is that something possible with pure CSS ?

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="fixed-part">
  This will always be 60px big
  </div>
  <div id="dynamic-part">
    This can grow and so should be scrollable<br><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="addContent()">Add content</a><br><br>
    <div id="insert">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#fixed-part {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 1px pink;
}

#dynamic-part {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to help:
https://jsfiddle.net/bz0b4ydz/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use the flexbox model, then this is easy:

```js
var count = 1;//demo purpose

function addContent() {
  let div = document.getElementById("insert");
  divChild = document.createElement('div');
  divChild.setAttribute('class', 'content');
  divChild.innerHTML = 'New content ' + count;
  div.insertBefore(divChild, div.firstChild);// prepend new div
  count++ // demo update count
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#fixed-part {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* or 
                       no height set but the full flex set : 
                       flex:1 0 60px;*/
  height: 60px;
  /* can be avoid, see previous comment */
  border: solid 1px pink;
}

#dynamic-part {
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="fixed-part">
    This will always be 60px big
  </div>
  <div id="dynamic-part">
    This can grow and so should be scrollable<br><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="addContent()">Add content</a><br><br>
    <div id="insert">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, the snippet works exactly as I want. I'll consider as the valid answer as soon as I have implemented it. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

You need a condition in your case :

```js
If( maxHeightReached ){
  scrollable();
}
```

In that case, you could use javascript to keep track of an element's height. But it's not easy to come up with a code here because it really depends on what you're trying to do.

Hope it helps.